# How to Find Magento Missing Order and what is the cause of it

Tags: magento2

Customer Place order payments received with no corresponding orders. From the customer's perspective, they had submitted an order and paid us but nothing was appearing in our order history on the admin side in the sales order grid, just a skipped increment_id.
I have checked the `quote` table there is `order_reserved_id` which is the same as order `increment_id` but I query the same `increment_id` in the `sales_order` table query return null.

> Q1: how to find all missing orders.

> Q2: How to debug this issue.

> Q3: what are the possible causes of this issue?

I Have tried different queries (match the reserved_order_id of quote table with increment_id of sales_order table) to find out the missing entries in the sales_order table. I don't know if this is the right way to find the missing order. we are using the Meetanshi_Paya module as a payment method with Magento 2.4.3.